# Alfresco or OpenKM

Tags: alfresco, dms

I'm investigating OpenKM and Alfreasco to integrate a DMS with a Python based ERP. Of course, the DMS should be feature rich in its own too.

After searching the web I could not find any clear and simple comparison of their feature sets. I would be interested both in their commercial offers and community editions, but event that distinction wasn't clear (is it only about support services?)

any feedback would be greatly appreciated!

thx

Comment: I don't know anything about OpenKM but in Alfresco's case, the biggest distinction between Community and Enterprise is the ability to get commercial support for the Enterprise edition. The software is virtually identical--it actually comes from the same code line. The Enterprise edition adds JMX, out-of-the-box clustering, XAM, and support for commercial databases and application servers.

Answer (score 0):

I think the preview function in OpenKM is more well than Alfresco.
And OpenKM is easy to use in a short time. configruation is more easy such as 'Search'...

Answer (score 0):

In your case, pure repository storage, the integration with thirdparty apps with webservices is one of the advantages you have with OpenKM. You have a set of SDK libraries ( you can find more information https://docs.openkm.com/ ) what he lps you to make a rapid integration with thirdparty software. I think in the past I have seen a python wrapper https://github.com/openkm/python-wrapper.